# Why is this code not working (i'm new to programming, python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

guesses = 3
number = random.randint(1, 10)
print (number) #<- To test what number im supposed to write.

while guesses > 0: # When you have more than 0 guesses -> guess another number
    guess = input("Guess: ")

    if guess == number : # If guess is equal to number -> end game
        print ('Your guess is right!.')
        break


    if guess != number : # If not number -> -1 guess
        print ("Nope!")
        guesses -= 1

    if guesses == 0: #If all 3 guesses are made -> end game
        print("That was it! Sorry.")
        print(number,"was the right answer!")
```

What am i doing wrong?
I can't figure it out, i hope you can help ^-^

And if you are able to teach me how to improve my programming then feel free to write me how to do it! Im open for learning new stuff btw sorry for my bad english :3 (edit: When i guess the right number, it still says "Nope!" and i have to guess another number.)

Comment: What is not working? What do you expect as output and what is instead the actual output?

Comment: When i guess the right number it still says that the guess is wrong so i don't know what's wrong.

Comment: This looks like Python3. If so, use `guess = int(input("Guess: "))` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like Python3. If so, use `guess = int(input("Guess: "))` instead.

In Python3 [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string and you're comparing that string to an integer which will never work. So convert the return value of `input()` to an integer to be sure you're comparing apples to apples.

Comment: You should put a little bit more information in there.  For example, he should probably make sure the input *can* be converted to an integer.  Otherwise, he'll be back here in another half-hour asking "Why is this code not working?"

Comment: Thanks, @zondo. I'll augment it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put int in front of input, so:

```
guess = int(input("Guess: "))
```

This will turn guess into an integer, so the code recognises it.

Answer (score 0):

The `input()` command returns a string and a string is not equal to a number (`"3" == 3` evaluates to `false`). You can use the `int(...)` function to turn a string (or floating-point number) into an integer.

I'm assuming you're using Python 3.x given that `print` is a function. If you were using Python 2.x, you should use `raw_input()` instead, as `input()` causes the interpreter to treat what was entered as Python code and execute it (like the `eval(...)` function does).

In 99.999 % of all cases, you do **not** want to execute user input. ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Another rather major thing your program needs is to prompt the user so they know what they will be doing with your program exactly. I've added the prompt accordingly.

```
import random

print ("Hello. We are going to be playing a guessing game where you guess a random number from 1-10. You get three guesses.")
number = random.randint(1, 10)
# print (number) #<- To test what number im supposed to write.
guesses = 3
while guesses > 0: # When you have more than 0 guesses -> guess another number
    guess = input("Enter your guess: ")

    if guess == number : # If guess is equal to number -> end game
        print ('Your guess is right!.')
        break


    if guess != number : # If not number -> -1 guess
        print ("Nope!")
        guesses -= 1

    if guesses == 0: #If all 3 guesses are made -> end game
        print("That was it! Sorry.")
        print(number, "was the right answer!")
```